# Overwrite the layout of a form from a custom theme

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, forms

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I have a `app/design/frontend/Company_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Customer/layout` directory with numerous XML files (like, for instance, customer_account_create.xml) from wich a overwrite default pages/sections layous.

I don't have the XML file responsible for the layout of the *Reset your password* page.

What is its name and where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Reset Password" link URL is `/customer/account/createpassword/`, so the related layout file is located in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_createpassword.xml`. You can put it into your theme file to override it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution _and_ the valuable explanation.

Comment: You seem like a very knowledgeable person when it comes to Magento. Will you be kind enough to answer the topic **[Assign all products in a category to all it's ancestor categories automatically, in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208650/assign-all-products-in-a-category-to-all-its-ancestor-categories-automatically)**? Thanks a lot!